# resolver problema do google speed insights

Tags: wordpress, cache, pagespeed-insights

no google speed insights aparece esse erro : "Aproveitar cache do navegador
A definição de uma data de validade ou de uma idade máxima nos cabeçalhos de HTTP para recursos estáticos instrui o navegador a carregar os recursos transferidos anteriormente a partir do disco local e não por meio da rede.
Aproveite o cache do navegador para os seguintes recursos que podem ser armazenados em cache:"
Qual plugin resolve isso, ou se não houver plugins, qual a melhor forma de resolver esse problema?? abraço a todos!! obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, Horácio.

Não é exatamente plugin a ser instalado. As normas que influenciam no PageSpeed são bem explicadas nos sites WebPageTest.Org e no GTMetrix.

No seu caso, o arquivo .HTAACESS, deve resolver. Cria um arquivo chamado ".htaaccess" na pasta principal do seu site com o código exemplo abaixo.

O que ocorrerá?

Quando o navegador carregar o site, o arquivo htaacess indicará que alguns arquivos podem ser cacheados por X tempo.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: oi, deu certo em parte...só ainda apareceu o arquivo: http://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js (60 minutos) Esse ainda aparece, mas todos os demais que apareciam nesse tópico, sumiram, então, o caminho é esse mesmo!! obrigado por enquanto!!

Comment: Esse outro que aparece você não tem controle porque não está no seu servidor. O que você pode fazer é fazer o download dele, inserir no seu projeto e então será servido com sua configuração. Que bom que ajudou. Se for a melhor resposta, não deixe de marcá-la. Abraço.